# Table title in uppercase ieeetran class

Tags: tables, ieeetran

I'm using the `\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}` and the table title appears in lower case letters as: (Table I.) 
But, it is supossed that whitin this class the table title should go in uppercase, I'm just wondering what my problem is about.

here is a basic example:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\caption{Comparison}
\label{tab:1}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{*7c}
\hline
{} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Medium \\Reflectivity \% \end{tabular}& \multicolumn{3}{c}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Sub-bands' \\FWHM [pm]\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Sub-bands' \\Distance [pm]\end{tabular}}\\
\hline
Design S1 & 30 & 40 & 40 & 40 & 100 & 300 \\
S1 & 31.5 & 40.8 & 42.8 & 37.76 & 104 & 294 \\
Design S2 & 30 & 40 & 40 & 40 & 200 & 500 \\
S2 & 30.7 & 40.3 & 39.8 & 39.3 & 194 & 490 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please show us a minimal working example so that we do not have to guess. Thanks.

Comment: I get uppercase "TABLE" when taking out `babel`, so I guess that's the culprit.

Comment: Unrelated: don't use the `cmex10` option to `amsmath`; it is only for compatibility with ***very old*** TeX distributions. And “very old” means about 20 years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the class `IEEEtran` defines

```
\def\tablename{TABLE}
```

the package `babel` (rather, the language-specific file `english.ldf`) re-defines it back to

```
\def\tablename{Table}
```

Adding (thanks to egreg for the suggestion)

```
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand*{\tablename}{TABLE}}
```

in the preamble *after* `\usepackage{babel}` should fix it.